# Share ssh key between partitions

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

On my workstation I run two partitions - Ubuntu 14 and Ubuntu 16. Both have the same IP but they have different ssh keys. Every time I reboot into the other and try logging remotely I have to clear `.ssh/known_hosts` on my laptop. Is there a way how to copy the credentials from one partition and use it in the other?

Comment: Why not just `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and `ssh-copy-id` from each installation?

Comment: You can copy the host keys from `/etc/ssh/ssh_host*` from one partition to the other.

Comment: I agree with @user4556274's comment. An other method, on the laptop, is to manually merge the know_hosts entries. when the ssh client finds a valid matching entry, it doesn't complain because there's also an other *invalid* matching entry. This still allows to know if you're login in Ubuntu14 or Ubuntu16 (using ssh -v etc ...)

Comment: @A.B merging known hosts seems as the easiest solution in fact. I didn't know you could run two keys at the same time.

Comment: use case when a sftp server you don't own is actually more than one: a cluster behind a VIP

Answer (score 0):

You might try running rsync in a `.bashrc` or `.profile` script... so you always get the newest from whichever OS is active.